# Search email addresses in ElasticSearch by regexp

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I search in Elastic by regexp to find email addresses?

I try like that:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "data": {
        "value": "[\\w\\'\\.\\_\\+\\-]+@[\\w]+[\\w\\-\\.]*\\.[\\w]+",
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get nothing.

There https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-regexp-query.html written that simbol @ means any symbol and therefore it should to be escaped.

Therefore I try like that:

```
{
      "query": {
        "regexp": {
          "data": {
            "value": "\\@",
            "flags": "ALL"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and like that:

```
{
          "query": {
            "regexp": {
              "data": {
                "value": "\\@",
                "flags": "ALL"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

but I get nothing again.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I use Elastic Search of 5.2 version on Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Data samples:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/index_type/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"data":"some text some text some text some text admin@company.comsome text some text some text "}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"data":"some text some text hr@company.comsome text some text "}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"data":"some text some text webmaster@company.comsome text some text "}
```

and searching query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/index_type/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "query": {
       "regexp": {
          "data": {
            "value": "\\@",
            "flags": "ALL"
          }
       }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: I found that while indexing of data Elastic use standart analyzer if other is not specified in mapping. "The standard analyzer divides text into terms on word boundaries" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: Also I found a url-email tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html . I will try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `"[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+"` regexp to find email addresses. Then run the following query find all email address**

```
GET /company/employee/_search
{
   "query": {
       "regexp": {
          "data": {
            "value": "[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+",
            "flags": "ALL"
          }
       }
   }
}
```

**Here `company` as index, `employee` as type and `data` as field name, then insert the following data to check your query works:**

```
POST /company/employee/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"data":"admin@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"data":"hr@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"data":"webmaster@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"data":"abc@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"data":"ahmed@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"data":"md@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"7"}}
{"data":"boss@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"8"}}
{"data":"amd@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"9"}}
{"data":"ad@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"10"}}
{"data":"ed@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"11"}}
{"data":"etc@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"12"}} 
{"data":"f23f23f23f23f23 d32d23d32d d32d2 3d 23"} 
{"index":{"_id":"13"}} 
{"data":"d23d32 d32d23d32 etc@company.com d3d23d23"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. But when I added more data like that:

{"data":"etc@company.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"12"}}
{"data":"f23f23f23f23f23 d32d23d32d d32d2 3d 23"}
{"index":{"_id":"13"}}
{"data":"d23d32 d32d23d32 etc@company.com d3d23d23"}

these data also are queried by your query.

Comment: Use `"[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+"` this will match any email. Check I have update my answer.

Comment: Not quite)) Try to add follows and to search:

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/company/employee/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"index":{"_id":"14"}}
{"data":"some text fewfewfewfewewGgmail.com some text "}
{"index":{"_id":"15"}}
{"data":" some text  fewfewfewfewew-gmail.com some text  "}
{"index":{"_id":"16"}}
{"data":"some text  fewfewfewfewew0gmail.com some text  "}
'

Comment: In Elastic Search regexp symbol @ means any symbol.

Comment: This may help You [Improve search experience using email](https://qbox.io/blog/improving-search-experience-by-using-email-tokenizers-ngram-and-phonetic-concepts-1)

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me (using devtools in kibana) for index `yourindex` and keyword type field `yourfield.keyword`:

```
GET yourindex/_search
{ 
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "yourfield.keyword": {
        "value": "[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\%\\+\\-]+\\@[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}",
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```